# How do I sort a dictionary by key ascending & value descending?

Tags: python, sorting

I'd like to sort dictionary like below:

from

```
unsorted_list :  {'F': 3, 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 2, 'E': 2, 'D': 1,}
```

to

```
sorted_list :  {'D': 1, 'A': 1, 'E': 2, 'C': 2, 'B': 2, 'F': 3,}
```

So,

1. sorting by value Ascending then,
2. sorting by key Descending

How can I do this by python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries preserve order of insertion, so if you want to re-order them, you need to build a new dict where you insert the items in the desired order.  You can do this pretty easily by sorting the dict's `items()` and then passing the result to `dict()`:

```
>>> d = {'F': 3, 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 2, 'E': 2, 'D': 1,}
>>> dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: (-i[1], i[0]), reverse=True))
{'D': 1, 'A': 1, 'E': 2, 'C': 2, 'B': 2, 'F': 3}
```

Note that if dictionary ordering is important to your use case, you might want to use an `OrderedDict`, which has more robust support for rearranging items in-place.

Comment: worth noting is that adding a new element to the dict in this case will throw off the order again. Dicts are not intended to represent data in any particular order, and older versions of python do not even preserve insertion order  (so this solution would not work in older versions of python).